# Projection linear transformation: explain the wording

Tags: linear-algebra

A question begins with:

> Let $T:R^2\to R^2$ be a projection operator onto the X axis in
>   parallel with line $y = 2x$.

On one hand, it says $T$ projects into the X axis, so $T \vec v$ should be the X-axis element of $\vec v$ (i.e. the shadow that $\vec v$ drops on the X axis).

But then, what do they mean by "in parallel with line ..."?

Please help me understand the wording.

BTW, the rest of the question goes like this:

> Find the matrix representation of $T^\star$ (the Hermitian adjoint) in the standard basis $B={(1,0), (0,1)}$.
>   Is $T$ a normal operator?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, so $0,0$ gets projected down to $0$. But in general, the projection isn't 'straight down' like what you're assuming.

For example, the point $(1,2)$ gets projected to $0$ as well, since the line with slope $2$ going through the point $(1,2)$ passes through the origin. Similarly, $(2,3)$ will be projected to $1$.

Comment: Please explain. What do you mean by "projected to 1"? The operator is $T:R^2\to R^2$ so it should project into $R^2$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Ilya: Sure, but the $y$-element is always $0$. So 'projected to $1$' is the same as 'projected to $(1,0)$.